# Pktgen Dpdk different socket ID on different cores error

Tags: transmission, traffic

I am facing the error " port 0 on socket ID 0 has different socket ID on lcore 1 socket ID 1" whenever I run Pkt gen Dpdk. I am running this on Host Machine. Pktgen Dpdk runs fine when I run it on Virtual Machines but gives error on Host Machine. Any solution Please!

[image: Pktgen Dpdk Command]

[image: Pktgen Dpdk Error]

Comment: Please do not use pictures of text include the text in the question. what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: OK @David . I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Comment: @saifullah it will much easier to debug and help if you had shared details about `1) version of DPDk, 2) version of pktgen 3) Host CPU layout via lspcu or dpdk-cpulayout.py and 4) arguemtns used in pktgen`. can you please update

Comment: To add context to the @David 's comment, When you include the typed out commands, future users with similar issues are able to find this page through the equivalent searches. searching images makes it easier on the next guy. Not trying to be picky, just considerate of the next guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK pktgen relies on the user to share lcore mask matching to NUMA-Socket on which NIC port exists. That for ***higher performance, dpdk-pktgen mandates the NIC NUMA and CPU core NUMA should be the same***. Failing to do so, will lead to `port 0 on socket ID 0 has different socket ID on lcore 1 socket ID 1`.

Solution: either use `lscpu` or `dpdk-cpulayout` to identify the core mask or lcoremask necessary for NUMA-0. Then run the application with new core mask.

example:

1. On non dell servers these can be `-c 0xf0` or `-l 2,3,4,5`
2. on dell server this can be `-c 0x154` or `-l 2,4,6`